# Does Shindig support OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-shindig

guys. As mentioned in the title,I wonder whether Shindig implement OAuth2.0 or not? I found an url:http://codereview.appspot.com/3138041/.When I startup the tomcat,however,it throws following exception:
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to www.google-analytics.com/www.google-analytics.com/2404:6800:8005:0:0:0:0:61 timed out
I am not sure how to fix this problem and does anyone who encountered this problem before can give me some hints?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the 2.5 branch of Shindig does support OAuth 2.0.  Shindig contains both a client and provider implementation.  The exception you are seeing when starting Tomcat probably has to do with the fact one of the features in Shindig points to that URL and for one reason or another it cannot access the URL.  For the most part Shindig should still function properly.